# Wordpress, Polylang, перевод пользовательского меню

Tags: wordpress, menu

Доброго времени суток! 
У меня пользовательская тема сайта на вордпресс. Меню выводится просто функцией `wp_nav_menu()`. 
Установлен Polylang, пункты меню не переводятся сами по себе. Ответ не нашла нигде. 
Можно, конечно, вывести с помощью функции `pll_current_language` (определить язык и подключить нужное меню), но мне кажется, я просто что-то не сделала. 
Вопрос, что же?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно создать два меню:

**Первое** для русского языка, добавить в него ссылки на русские страницы, и в области отображения поставить галочку только для русского языка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Второе** меню создать для английского языка, добавить в него ссылки на страницы на английском, и в области отображения поставить галочку только для английского языка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А не можете подсказать почему у меня "Область отображения" может быть пустой? Три языка созданы, страницы переведены, а вот меню не могу назначить область эту - пусто

Comment: Возможно у вас область для меню не зарегистрированная. Для каждой области нужно делать регистрацию в файле functions.php